# Picocli, how to recognise presence of option with optional value and custom type converter

Tags: java, picocli

Picocli v2.3.0.

```
@CommandLine.Option(names = {"--number-headings"},
                    arity = "0..1",
                    paramLabel = "levels",
                    description = {"Adds numbers to headings. Optional parameter to set the heading levels to be numbered.",
                                   "eg. 2-4"})
public HeadingNumberingRange numberHeadings;
```

Custom type converter is registered and working correctly when a value is provided (`mycommand --number-headings 2-5`). But numberHeadings remains `null` if called like: `mycommand --number-headings`.

Example at http://picocli.info/man/2.x/#_optional_values suggests that a `String` typed option will receive an empty string when no value is provided.

So the empty string is the *default value when option is present but no value is provided*.

This allows us to distinguish between 3 situations:

1. Option not present (we get `null`)
2. Option present with no value (we get empty string)
3. Option present with value (we get value)

With a custom `ITypeConverter`, the `convert()` method of the `ITypeConverter` is not called when there is no value provided. So what is the equivalent *default value when option is present but no value is provided* for custom types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [raising this](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/325) on the picocli issue tracker.

As of picocli [3.0.0-alpha-5](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha-5), custom type converters can map the empty String (when the option is present without a value) to a custom default value. This functionality is included in the [picocli 3.0.0](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/releases/tag/v3.0.0) GA release that just came out.